# use string variable as format string in \begin{tabu}

Tags: strings, tabu

I have the following problem. I'm using the `tabu` package to create tables but instead of a format string like this: `\begin{tabu}{ccc}` I want to use a format string like this (as string variable): `\begin{tabu}{\reptemp}`.

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forloop,tabu}

\begin{document}

\def\reptemp{}      

\newcounter{ct}

    \forloop{ct}{1}{\value{ct} < 5}%
    {%
        \g@addto@macro\reptemp{c}
    }

\begin{tabu}{\reptemp}
\end{tabu}

\end{document}
```

And get the following compiling error:

`! Package array Error: Illegal pream-token (\reptemp): 'c' used.`

I hope you have a tip for my how I can solve this problem.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `tabu` environment doesn't do expansion on the preamble argument.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forloop,tabu}

\def\reptemp{}
\makeatletter
\newcounter{ct}

    \forloop{ct}{1}{\value{ct} < 5}%
    {%
        \g@addto@macro\reptemp{c}
    }
\makeatother

\newenvironment{xtabu}[1]
  {\begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup
   \unexpanded{\begin{tabu}}{\unexpanded\expandafter{#1}}}\x}
  {\end{tabu}}


\begin{document}
\begin{xtabu}{\reptemp}
1&2&3&4
\end{xtabu}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to expand the macro before passing it to the environment:

```
\def\starttabu#1{\begin{tabu}{#1}}

\expandafter\starttabu\expandafter{\reptemp}
```